# Alternative wording for "Falling into pitfalls"

Tags: synonyms

Context: Are you fully knowledgeable of the subject, or are you falling into the common pitfalls?

I don't like having falling and pitfall together. I also think "experiencing the common pitfalls" is a little too formal for the context; I would prefer to keep a casual tone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

e.g.

- Most beginners succumb to the common pitfalls of Javascript having untyped variables.
- We are often seduced by common pitfalls of a first date, and reveal too much information about ourselves.
- Are you fulfilling the common pitfalls of DIY investmenting by putting all your eggs into the same basket?
- We are often caught unaware by the common pitfalls of buying a first home.
- People need to stop being caught up by the common pitfalls of having a million dollar bar-mitsvah party for your only kid.
- As expected, she was trapped in the common pitfalls of excessive modularization.
- Most people lure themselves into the common pitfalls of the theory of Evolution, like  asking their dog to be turned into a unicorn.
- She had quickly waltzed herself into the common pitfalls of falling in love.
- In a survivalists' world of Hollywood, we clamber and shove each other into the common pitfalls of stardom.

You get the idea.

Comment: "caught up by the common pitfalls" is what I think I'll go with. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think if you're formal enough to use "fully knowledgeable of the subject", you're safe to use [*encountering*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/encounter), which has the connotation of meeting with adversity (such as a *pitfall*).

More casual phrasing might include *meeting*, *experiencing*, facing, running into, coming across, coming upon, chance upon, and happening upon.

Answer (score 1):

The query sentence sounds pretty strained and unidiomatic. If I had the choice, I'd completely reword it:

> Do you know everything about the subject, or are you falling into the usual traps?

(Incidentally, not being knowledgeable about a subject doesn't necessarily imply 'falling into pitfalls'.)

Answer (score 1):

- falling into traps
- making rookie mistakes
- making mountains out of molehills

Comment: I don't think "making mountains out of molehills" applies. I think it has a different meaning.

Comment: @MikeCole - if you are new at something like coding then you might work on something in such a way that you create 100s of lines of codes to do something, to only find from an experienced coder that there is indeed a function that already does it for you in one line of code.  You made a mountain out of a molehill.